# Unix system programming - unzipping a file programmatically

Tags: c, unzip, systems-programming

What I need to do is unzip a file, (.gz or .z), read the first line and do some stuff according to the first line read. But the C standard library doesn't seem to offer a way to do this.

Is the a platform-independent way to do it?

Comment: just use gzip and gunzip

Comment: Isn't it a task which better fits bash scripting again C code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use "zlib", the library that performs compression and decompression:

http://www.zlib.net/

It's included in the base of all Unix distributions, and you can easily link your program against it for the windows version and ship the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The [info-zip](http://www.info-zip.org/) libraries are *quite* portable.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to platform-independent, you'd have to have the unzipping code in your program. Likely, you'd want to link against a third-party library, such as [ZLib](http://zlib.net) which is standard on Unix systems, or use the [DLL](http://www.zlib.net/DLL_FAQ.txt) when on Windows.

The rest is pretty simple: use ZLib to unzip the file to a temporary location, read the file as normal, then remove the file when you're done.

Comment: You don't even need a temporary file; zlib allows you to compress/decompress streaming in memory.

Comment: Is the in memory thing faster than fiddling around with a temp file?